# rpm & rpmbuild - using global environment variable in the %files section

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have been struggling for a while with this one.
So I wrote a .specs file for my project and everything went fine. The rpm is built, the installation is smooth... but then I got some trouble because now, I have to use a custom global environment variable to set the install path.

This would give a %files section as such :

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
$INSTALLPATH/Crystal/bin/Crystal.jar
```

Where Crystal is my project name, and INSTALLPATH is defined within env thanks to the export commandline. Then, when running 
    buildrpm -ba Crystal.specs
I have the following error:

```
error: File must begin with "/" : $INSTALLPATH/Crystal/bin/Crystal.jar
```

I have tried to define a macro inside the .rpmmacros file as such : 
    %_installpath $INSTALLPATH

And in my specs file, when i do
    echo %{_installpath}
I get the value I set in the .rpmmacros. But if I use it in %files:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_installpath}/Crystal/bin/Crystal.jar
```

I get the same error again!

```
error: File must begin with "/" : $INSTALLPATH/Crystal/bin/Crystal.jar
```

I also tried defining a variable with the specs file and I have the same sad result. It looks like as long as my variable/macro is referencing to $INSTALL, then %files won't accept it. But I have to use this env variable!

So that's all I could think about. Anyone got a clue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%files` section does not expand shell variables. You cannot do this that way.

You have a couple options that I can see offhand. You can

- generate a file with a list of your files (during `%install` or what-have-you) and then use `%files -f files.lst`
- expand `$INSTALLPATH` at rpm macro definition time with:

  ```
  # For RPM >= 4.7.0
  %_installpath %{getenv:INSTALLPATH}
  # For RPM < 4.7.0
  %_installpath %{lua:print(os.getenv("INSTALLPATH"))}
  ```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I used the first solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Etan Reisner: You can use shell variables in `%files` section the same way as anywhere else in the spec, although that might be pretty ugly and unreadable. E.g. using `%(echo $INSTALLPATH/Crystal/bin/Crystal.jar)` should achieve what the OP wanted.

Comment: @doktor5000 That's not the `%files` section expanding shell variables though (and I don't believe the `%files` section does that). That's `rpm` doing the expansion at parse time manually because you used the `%(...)` macro. But yes, that would (possibly) have worked... assuming `%(...)` expansions are performed in the right macro scope.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Definitely works in `%files` section, we use it for some particularly ugly packages to tag certain files dynamically with `%lang($lang)` and basically create that part of the `%files` section on the fly. But your proposed solution with the files list is probably much cleaner for the OP :)

Comment: @doktor5000 What specifically works in the `%files` section? An entry like `/usr/lib/$shellvar`? Your dynamically created file list contains `%lang($lang) /path/to/file` in it? Or does it contain `%lang(en) /path/to/file`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: This is basically what I use in `%files`
`%(for lang in %langs ; do
  echo "%%lang($lang) /path/to/file-$lang"
done)` where `%langs` is a list of locales.

Comment: @doktor5000 Yes, that's an *explicit* invocation of the shell with a variable being defined in *that* shell script (as that's a shell for loop). That's not at all the same as the `%files` section expanding shell variables in normal usage. Try using a shell variable from your `%build` or `%install` sections in that loop or just using the variable in the `%files` list directly and you'll see what I mean about it not working.