# Pass multiple variables into rpmbuild as parameters for spec file

Tags: yaml, rpmbuild

### Problem

I have two env variables in my buildspec.yml

```
env:
  variables:
    BUILD_VERSION: "0.0.1"
    BUILD_RELEASE: "1"
```

I would like to pass them into an `rpmbuild` command but I cant seem to get the syntax correct.

---

### My Attempt

```
- rpmbuild --define "_topdir `pwd`" --define "_version '$BUILD_VERSION'" --define "_release '$BUILD_RELEASE'" -bb ./mydirectory/myspecfile.spec
```

I've tried several other versions of this with no luck.  An assist here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to use

```
rpmbuild --define '_version 0.0.1'
```

but in that case you need to have the variable _version defined in your spec file; something like:

```
%{!?_version: %define _version 0.0.0 }
Version: %{_version}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I was trying to keep the variables defined in the env for the buildspec.  Is that possible? I want to have them defined at the top of the buildspec so they're easily changed for new builds.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with 'buildspec'. I didn't find a way to defining variables like *Version* directly from the outside, that's why I came up with this workaround...

Comment: Right, I thought I explained it in the question.  What I mean is instead of using rpmbuild --define '_version 1.0.0', I would define the env variables as shown above in the buildspec.yml and call the buildrpm from there while passing in the env variables as definitions for the _version and _build inside the .spec.  I'm familiar with defining them in the spec but I was hoping to use the env variables in the buildrpm call.

Comment: I don't know about using environment variables in a spec file... take a look here for using environment variables in a spec file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25895545/2082964

Comment: I think we're having a misunderstanding here. I'll just accept your answer and re-post the question more clearly.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and was able to resolve with this syntax

```
rpmbuild --bb --define "_topdir ${rpmdir}" --define "PRODUCT_VERSION 1.0" --buildroot /home/devuser/buildTest/buildroot --target x86_64 ./SPECS/html5.spec
```

Note the double quotes is important.